# document.getElementById to inner.Text doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm currently coding a javascript calculation for shopping cart webpage. But I have a problem with my subtotal, everything works well only the sub Total of everything for payment is the wrong one.

Here's my table code where I put all the classes for the subtotal function:

```
<tr>
  <td>$no</td>
  <td>$item[item_name]</td>
  <td>
    $item[item_price]<input
      type="hidden"
      id="only-number-input"
      class="cart_price"
      value="$item[item_price]"
    />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input
      type="number"
      class="text-center cart_qty"
      onchange="subTotal()"
      value="$item[qty]"
      min="1"
      max="10"
    />
  </td>
  <td class="cart_total"></td>
  <td>
    <form action="manage-cart.php" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" name="remove">
        REMOVE
      </button>
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="$item[item_name]" />
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And here is where I put the subtotal ID:

```
<div class="border-top py-4">
  <h4 class="font-baloo font-size-20">Subtotal</h4>
  <h5 class="text-danger" id="sub_total"></h5>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning mt-3">Proceed to Buy</button>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
var cart_price = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_price');
var cart_qty = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_qty');
var cart_total = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_total');
var sub_total = document.getElementById('sub_total');

function subTotal() {
    sub_total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cart_price.length; i++) {
        var calculation = (cart_price[i].value) * (cart_qty[i].value);
        cart_total[i].innerText = calculation;
        sub_total = sub_total + calculation;
    }
    sub_total.innerText = sub_total;
}
subTotal();
```

Comment: one variable can't be two different things......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resetting `sub_total` to `0` inside your function so it is no longer a DOM element reference.

You can use a different name for the value inside the function. In this example I have used `sub_total_value`:

```
var cart_price = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_price');
var cart_qty = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_qty');
var cart_total = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_total');
var sub_total = document.getElementById('sub_total');

function subTotal() {
    var sub_total_value = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < cart_price.length; i++) 
    {
        var calculation = (cart_price[i].value) * (cart_qty[i].value);
        cart_total[i].innerText = calculation;
        sub_total_value = sub_total_value + calculation;
    }
    sub_total.innerText = sub_total_value;
}
subTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code has two variables named `sub_total`. Try renaming one.